# Accessing node from DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList

Tags: c#, qtp, hp-uft

How to access nodes from DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList, tree having multiple nodes and multiple branches. By finding position of node evoke click action or event. In application only single tree data structure we are using. We tried following lines of code to achieve same.  I am new to this UFT testing tools.

```
SwfWindow("softwareName 5.0.209.32468").SwfObject("navBarControl1")
SwfWindow("softwareName 5.0.209.32468").SwfListView("navBarControl1").Object
SwfWindow("softwareName 5.0.209.32468").SwfObject("navBarControl1").Object.Controls
```

Platform: Windows Application.

Don't know how to use those.

Comment: So what´s your exact problem, and what does work, what doesn´t? "Soem issue while accessing MDI links" is not exactly a precise description.

Comment: @TheBlastOne means I want to access mdi element at exact position, how can i archive same.. object dont have unique property or name not I am able to cast object.. any help

Comment: *Welcome to StackOverflow!* Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ankush, please edit your question so that one who is good in automation abd c# (Swf) has a chance to find all info to understand the problem at hand. For example, I don´t know what MDI element you mean (MDI means "multiple document interface" to me...?), and what you mean by "exact position". Don´t just distribute the info through comments.

Comment: @Andreas -- "Welcome to StackOverflow" is not exactly what I´d say to a ~1300 respect points user ;)

Comment: @TheBlastOne Please check out edited question. Simply what I want to find node from tree and click on it.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Yes I already go through those guidelines. Include tag cos search engine find it better way if someone looking of sort of question since its mix of different technologies. I would appreciate if you can answer my question rather than finding stupid things.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear

Comment: @TheBlastOne you did see the italic letters, didn't you?

Comment: @AnkushMadankar Watch your tongue! You obviously did not read these guidelines, as they explicitely state *Stack Overflow is optimized so that **tags are indexed by search engines** along with the content of the question.*, and SO is a platform based on the principals of CC where everyone tries to make improvements to questions and answers, even if it is just for [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Italics: What do they mean there? (No offense intended.)

Comment: @TheBlastOne kursiv ;)

Comment: @TheBlastOne Do you know how to use tree node object from object repository? I tried to save object and access same object by name by QTP click on some other node from tree..

Comment: @TheBlastOne Please send me ur email so that I can send u snaps and related problems that we are facing now.. or we can contact on whatsapp, send me contact no on my email. Please help.

Comment: Sorry no, I am here for the public question-and-answer thing, not for free one-on-one consulting chats.